# What molecule is mostly responsible for the smell of petrol/gasoline when I refill my car?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, environmental-chemistry, smell

Is it benzene or is there another aromatic molecule in gasoline with "heavier scents"? Does anybody know of a scientific investigation to provide evidence for an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you state, aromatic compounds such as benzene, naphthalene, xylene and toluene have noticeable odor (ergo "aromatic"). In addition, odorous [oganosulfur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organosulfur_compounds) compounds may remain, though in Europe and North America effort is made to remove them ([kerosene](https://www.marathonpetroleum.com/brand/content/documents/mpc/sds/0121MAR019.pdf) and heating oils may have higher amounts of oganosulfur contaminants).

In the US, Methyl tert-butyl ether (MTBE) was a common strong-smelling additive that raised octane number and reduced CO emission, but it has been largely phased-out because of it propensity to leak into and damage aquifers.

A [Safety Data Sheet](https://www.hess.com/docs/us-safety-data-sheets/gasoline-all-grades.pdf?sfvrsn=2) list some other chemicals that may have a noticable odor, such as ethanol (added for the same purpose as MBTE).

A trained nose can detect and identify any or all of these compounds, so it really depends on the particular petrol you buy. As a rough guide, the aromatics may have a "sweet' or fruity smell to some people, though naphthalene has the smell of moth-flakes, MBTE a "burning" odor, and sulfur compounds may smell like rotten garlic.